# beego,redefined 404 page is show html source code ,why?

Tags: beego

Here is my code:

```
func page_not_found(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    t,_:= template.ParseFiles(beego.BConfig.WebConfig.ViewsPath +"/404.html")
    data :=make(map[string]interface{})
    data["content"] = "page not found"
    t.Execute(rw, data)
}
func main() {
    beego.ErrorHandler("404",page_not_found)
    beego.Router("/", &controllers.MainController{})
    beego.Run()
}
```

I got this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It solved by encoding the file with utf-8 witout bom